# Get values based on minor timedelta in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with a big `DataFrame` indexed by two different datetime objects like this (imagine the date columns are datetime `Series`):

```
            Var1 Var2
date1 date2          
d1    d5      v1   v6
      d6      v2   v7
d2    d7      v3   v8
      d8      v4   v9
      d9      v5  v10
```

But I want to get the rows in which the difference of the `date2` column and the `date1` column is the minor. The `date2` column can only be greater or equal than `date1`. A desired output would be:

```
            Var1 Var2
date1 date2          
d1    d5      v1   v6
d2    d7      v3   v8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get difference of both levels with [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), if necessary get absolute values and get index of first minimal value per group by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html), last seelct rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['diff'] = np.abs(df.index.get_level_values('date1') - df.index.get_level_values('date2'))

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['diff'].idxmin()]
```

Solution without helper column, with helper `Series`:

```
lev1 = df.index.get_level_values('date1') 
lev2 = df.index.get_level_values('date1') 

s = pd.Series(np.abs(lev1- lev2), index=df.index)

df1 = df.loc[s.groupby(lev1).idxmin()]
```